# how to display a timer every second while my code is running on linux

Tags: c, linux

I'm working on a simple game where you guess a random number between 0 and 100. You have 7 seconds and 6 tries to guess it but I want to display the countdown timer while the game is running.
(00:07 00:06 00:05......00:00)
I tried to use `gotoxy` function to display the timer on the side but the displaying was a mess because `gotoxy` put the cursor on the next line after it's called. Or maybe I didn't use it right.

Is there a way to display the time (in seconds) without having a messy display?

Here is my try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>

/*void gotoxy(int x, int y){
    printf("%c[%d;%df",0x1b,y,x);
}*/

void timer();
int c=6;

void main ()
{
    system("clear");
    int  a, num=200;

    signal(SIGALRM,timer);

    srand(time(NULL));
    a=rand()%101;
    int i=1;

    printf("try to guess a number between 0 and 100 in 7 seconds , you have only 6 tries \n\t good luck\n");
    alarm(1);
    //gotoxy(50,2);
    printf("00:07\n");

    while ((a != num)&&(i<=7)) { 

        if (i==7) printf("no more tries !!!! \n");
        else printf("try: %d  \n ",i);

        printf("give a number  \n ");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        if (a>num) 
        printf("it's more ! \n ");
        else if (a<num) 
        printf("it's less ! \n ");
        else  
        printf("\t\tGreat ! you won !!! \n ");
i++;

    }

}

void timer(){
    if(c<0){
    printf ("you lost \n");
    exit(1);
    }
    else{ 
    //gotoxy(50,2);    
    printf("00:0%d\n",c);
    c--;
    alarm(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried with ncurse?

Comment: The answer is "sure, it's possible", but doing it nicely is going to substantially complicate your code because now you want to do two things at the same time: wait for input from the user and update the timer. You'll probably need to investigate something like ncurses, which is a library for managing text-based user interface, and you'll need to learn about programming with an event loop. There may be other ways of tackling this (run the timer in a background thread/process), but they're all going to require some research.

Comment: never heard of ncurses before but i searched it up just now and i'm not sure how this may help , the displaying would be still messy since the cursor whouldn't be put back where the main code left on .... i tried using thread to display the time but it also didn't help because the created thread and the main thread aren't working actually on the same same time and even the use of semaphore or mutex wouldn't help ... but again , i'm not sure .. i'm still new to all this